# How to change the settings in 22.04 of a known Wifi network you're not connected to?

Tags: networking, wireless, gnome, 22.04, settings

Opening the Wi-Fi settings there is a list of networks, but it's only possible to edit the settings of the network you're connected to.

IMHO that is a major (GNOME) regression from 20.04

How do I change/check the settings for a known WiFi network I'm not connected to?

Comment: Seems to have been fixed in GNOME 43, so you'd have to update your Ubuntu to a newer release to get that fix.  Maybe 22.10?  See bug: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-control-center/-/issues/1906

Answer (score 2):

I find it annoying as well. It makes using Ubuntu PC and being mobile, often changing networks and places, difficult.

You could use a command

`nm-connection-editor`

I think it opens a panel, that You are used to use.

Answer (score 1):

connection files in ls /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections directory
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/myconneciton.nmconnection
or with sed replace regex.